# How to merge two strings side by side in java

Tags: java, string

How can one append a paragraph string to another along **LHS** to **RHS** rather the default **TOP** to **BOTTOM** for `Strings`.

I mean say

```
 String par1 = "this paragraph consists\n"+
                        "of five lines which include\n"+
                         "line one \n"+ 
                         "line two \n"+ 
                        "and line three";

 String par2 = "this paragraph consists\n"+
                        "of six lines which include\n"+
                        "line one \n"+ 
                        "line two \n"+
                        "line three \n"+
                        "and line four";
 String TopBottomMerge = par1 +"\n"+ par2;
```

which makes :

```
 String TopBottomMerge = "
  this paragraph consists
  of five lines which include
  line one
  line two
  and line three

  this paragraph consists
  of six lines which include
  line one 
  line two
  line three
  and line four";
```

How is it possible to have

```
  String LhsRhsMerge = ???;
```

to give:

```
  "this paragraph consists          this paragraph consists
   of five lines which include      of six lines which include
   line one                         line one 
   line two                         line two 
   and line three                   line three 
                                    line four"
```

Comment: Is this JSP or is this Java?

Comment: Can you please explain why you need to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Use `par1.split("\n")` and `par2.split("\n")` to create two arrays, each of which holds the lines from the corresponding paragraph.

You can then iterate on these arrays with a `for` loop over index `i` from 0 the the length of the longest array, adding the lines at index `i` at each step.

Answer (score 0):

```
int indx = str.indexOf(" - ");
String a1 = str.substring(0, indx);
String a2 = str.substring(indx+3, str.length());
```

split() is a bit more computation intensive than indexOf()

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.  Basically the way suggested by Tugrul Ates above but insert spaces to format the lines so the right lines are lined up.

Alternate lines, append the left, then append spaces as needed, then append right.

```
/**
 * Merge the lines from these two Strings alternating left and right.
 * @param leftString the left lines
 * @param rightString the right lines
 * @return the merged lines
 */
private String mergeLeftRight(String leftString, String rightString) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String[] leftLines = leftString.split("\n");
    int leftSize = maxLength(leftLines) + 4; // max length of lines in left string

    String[] rightLines = rightString.split("\n");

    int leftIndex = 0;
    int rightIndex = 0;
    while (leftIndex < leftLines.length && rightIndex < rightLines.length) {
        if (leftIndex < leftLines.length) {
            String leftLine = leftLines[leftIndex++];
            sb.append(leftLine);
            appendSpaces(sb, leftSize - leftLine.length());
        }

        if (rightIndex < rightLines.length) {
            sb.append(rightLines[rightIndex++]);
        }

        sb.append("\n");
    }

    return sb.toString();
}

/**
 * Append spaces to the StringBuilder.
 * @param sb the StringBuilder
 * @param count the number of spaces to append
 */
private void appendSpaces(StringBuilder sb, int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        sb.append(" ");
    }
}

/**
 * Find the max length of the Strings in the array.
 * @param lines the array of Strings
 * @return the max length
 */
private int maxLength(String[] lines) {
    int max = 0;
    for (String line : lines) {
        max = Math.max(max, line.length());
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `Scanner' to read one line from each paragraph. Add some spaces or tabs or something and then and the line Frome the second paragraph. The greatest thing about doing it this way is the fact you can run this in a loop to achieve the same goal.